# Can't get Apache web server to show my django app

Tags: django, apache

On the server I can run python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 on the server and it renders my app fine.

When I try via Apache, I get the infinite load and nothing renders. Spent too much time trying to troubleshoot and can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated! Here's my configs.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

    Alias /static /home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/srf_news/static
    <Directory /home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/srf_news/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

      Alias /media /home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/srf_news/media
            <Directory /home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/srf_news/media>
                    Require all granted
            </Directory>

    <Directory /home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/srf_news/srf_news>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/srf_news/srf_news/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/srf_news python-home=/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv

    WSGIProcessGroup django_app
```

My app structure is:

```
└── heimat
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── srf_news
│   ├── admin_app
│   ├── articles
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── logs
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── media
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── simplification
│   ├── srf_integration
│   ├── srf_news
│   ├── static
│   ├── swagger_srgssr_contents_v1_0_3.yaml
│   └── templates
└── venv
    ├── bin
    ├── include
    ├── lib
    ├── lib64 -> lib
    └── pyvenv.cfg
```

My base directory is:

```
jordanstarrk_production@django-server:~/heimat$ ls -la
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data                www-data                4096 Jul  9 15:08 .
drwxr-x---  6 jordanstarrk_production jordanstarrk_production 4096 Jul  9 14:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x  8 www-data                www-data                4096 Jul  9 14:05 .git
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data                www-data                1356 Jul  9 13:07 .gitignore
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data                www-data                1070 Jul  9 13:07 LICENSE
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data                www-data                  12 Jul  9 13:07 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 12 www-data                www-data                4096 Jul  9 15:40 srf_news
drwxr-xr-x  5 jordanstarrk_production jordanstarrk_production 4096 Jul  9 15:08 venv
```

One directory lower is:

```
jordanstarrk_production@django-server:~/heimat/srf_news$ ls -la
total 444
drwxr-xr-x 12 www-data www-data    4096 Jul  9 15:40 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data    4096 Jul  9 15:08 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data    4096 Jul  9 13:07 .ebextensions
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data    4096 Jul  9 13:15 admin_app
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data    4096 Jul  9 13:15 articles
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data 1261568 Jul  9 13:07 db.sqlite3
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data    4096 Jul  9 13:15 logs
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data     687 Jul  9 13:07 manage.py
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     www-data    4096 Jul  9 15:40 media
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data     681 Jul  9 13:07 requirements.txt
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data    4096 Jul  9 13:15 simplification
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data    4096 Jul  9 13:15 srf_integration
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data    4096 Jul  9 14:55 srf_news
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data    4096 Jul  9 13:22 static
-rwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data    9396 Jul  9 13:07 swagger_srgssr_contents_v1_0_3.yaml
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data    4096 Jul  9 13:07 templates
jordanstarrk_production@django-server:~/heimat/srf_news$
```

Firewall rules are:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8000                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Error logs using sudo tail -n 100 /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
Current thread 0x00007f2d836ca780 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
[Sun Jul 09 21:16:02.269972 2023] [wsgi:warn] [pid 29417:tid 139833455191936] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=29417): Unable to stat Python home /home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv'
  sys.path = [
    '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv/lib/python310.zip',
    '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv/lib/python3.10',
    '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f2d836ca780 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
[Sun Jul 09 21:16:03.271890 2023] [wsgi:warn] [pid 29419:tid 139833455191936] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=29419): Unable to stat Python home /home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
[Sun Jul 09 21:16:03.275748 2023] [wsgi:warn] [pid 29418:tid 139833455191936] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=29418): Unable to stat Python home /home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv'
  sys.path = [
    '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv/lib/python310.zip',
    '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv/lib/python3.10',
    '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f2d836ca780 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv'
  sys.path = [
    '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv/lib/python310.zip',
    '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv/lib/python3.10',
    '/home/jordanstarrk_production/heimat/venv/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f2d836ca780 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

Comment: please post error.log

Comment: home and venv should also have group set to www-data

Comment: btw the error shows that Apache can start Python but is struggling with access rights  .... most of the time the reason for "no module named encodings"

Comment: Ok thanks. So I have 2 login users on the server: root user, and jordanstarrk_production. Do I need to create an apache user login on Ubuntu and login as that user? @Razenstein

Comment: no www-data is created by Apache. Just access rights to folders are necessary.

Comment: I think I found the root to my problem. It’s the environment variables. I have them all in bashrc. Sounds like that doesn’t work well in prod env with Apache